# Is it possible to load some component before "App" component? Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, splash-screen, angular2-bootstrapping

My application starts from `App` component:

```
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ App ]
...
```

This is my index.hmtl

```
...
<app>
 Loading...
</app>
...
```

But I want to make splash screen instead of just "Loading ... " message:

```
...
<app>
  <splash></splash>
</app>
...
```

Also I added splash screen to main module declarations:

```
...
declarations: [
  App,
  SplashScreen
],
...
```

But ... bootstrapping process starts from `App` component and `Splash` is not loaded.
How can I load Splash component before App component and use it?

Comment: You want to load an Angular2 component that is shown while Angular2 is loading and initializing? ;-)

Comment: Yes. But only initializing.

Comment: You can make the `AppComponent` as lightweight as possible and add an `<my-actual-app-component *ngIf="dataIsLoaded">my-actual-app-component>` if you think rendering your `AppComponent` is taking some time. Usually it's just the initialization of Angular2 itself.

Comment: Thanks for this approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't load a component without Angular, so you probably need to make a "static" splash screen/loading animation with pure HTML (and JS, if you need that).

Answer (score 2):

You can make the AppComponent as lightweight as possible and add an `<my-actual-app-component *ngIf="dataIsLoaded">my-actual-app-component>` if you think rendering your AppComponent is taking some time. Usually it's just the initialization of Angular2 itself.

Answer (score 0):

The app component would be the one you load from Angular 2. If you want a splash screen, you will need to do that in your `index.html`. From there you can add js and css to it if you want some sort of animation other than a static splash screen (i.e. a loading circle).